# Error class initialization in the provider?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

**Error view:**

> Target [App\Services\OrderServiceInterface] is not instantiable.

**Provider:**

```
   class OrderServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider
{
    /**
     * Bootstrap services.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function boot()
    {
        //
    }

    /**
     * Register services.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function register()
    {
        $this->app->bind('App\Services\OrderServiceInterface', 'App\Services\OrderService');
    }
}
```

Where **OrderServiceInterface** is interface:

```
<?php

namespace App\Services; 

interface OrderServiceInterface
{

    public function doSomethingUseful();

}
```

And **OrderService** is a specific class:

```
<?php

namespace App\Services;

class OrderService implements OrderServiceInterface
{
    public function doSomethingUseful()
    {
        return 'Output from DemoOne';
    }
}
```

**Usage:**

```
public function accept(Request $request, OrderServiceInterface $orderService) {}
```

Comment: Do you have the OrderService imported in the `AppServiceProvider`? And have you tried using the full name `'App\Services\OrderService'`

Comment: How is it possible to import my `OrderServiceProvider ` to `OrderServiceProvider `? Hm..

Comment: I have update question with full provider class

Comment: so do you have your custom provider registered in `config/app.php` in the 'providers' array?

Comment: Certainly: `App\Providers\OrderServiceProvider::class`

Comment: if you add ::class at the end you should avoid the single quotes, if you just set `'App\Providers\OrderServiceProvider'` then it should be in quotes. Can you debug by adding `dd('test')` inside your custom provider to make sure that it enters there at all

Comment: `public function register()
    {

        dd('d');}` It does not work. I get the same error

Comment: I'd add `public function provides() { return [App\Services\OrderInterface::class]; }` to your ServiceProvider Class too.

Comment: The same result

Comment: run a `composer dump-auto`?

Comment: Yes, seems I do somethong wrong, ot Laravel try to make instance from interface

Comment: Can you show `config/app.php` content

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your service provider seems like it is not registered try running:

```
composer dump-autoload

php artisan cache:clear
```

thanks to @adam

```
php artisan config:clear
```

Comment: I tried: no result: `BindingResolutionException {#398
  #message: "Target [App\Services\OrderServiceInterface] is not instantiable."`

Comment: when you debug now, does it goes into your register method inside the custom provider?

Comment: Sure, I have references

Comment: Can you just add `$this->app->bind('App\Services\OrderServiceInterface', 'App\Services\OrderService');` inside your `AppServiceProvider` register method, and make sure that the binding works at all?

Comment: seems like your custom provider is not being registered for some reason

Comment: Adam, yes it made result, it is launched!